# React Native Firebase Cloud Messaging push notification do not produce sound in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using react native firebase cloud messaging push notifications. And followed completed documentation as given https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage

Everything works fine but sound does not produce on iOS device when push notification arrives. Sound works perfectly on Android but not on iOS. Permissions are also added.

Versions I am using:

"react-native": "0.63.2",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.3.1",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.7.1",

Permission code:

```
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission({
    sound: true,
    alert: true,
  });
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED || authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
    return enabled
}
```

I have google and everything implemented as suggested but still notification do not produced sound.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your notification message structure?

Comment: @SaachiTech `Fcmex.push(users_list,
      notification: %{
        title: data.title,
        body: data.description,
        sound: "default"
      },
      data: data
    )`